# For Google Calendar Using mode=DAY link code, page displays one day, but not *TODAY* (displays prior day)

Tags: google-calendar-api

Goal
Display "TODAY" view of Google Calendar DAY view (not Agenda) in an embedded link code for iframe.

Observations
Using mode=DAY link code, page displays one day, but not *TODAY* (displays day before's day view).

Requirements
No desire to use AGENDA mode.  mode=AGENDA displays correct date (as expected).

Digging into the script for the site, it appears the "preloadStart" and "preloadEnd" variables are set to the day before (e.g. today is 20231227, but the preloadStart variable in the script gets set to 20231226).

https://storage.googleapis.com/support-forums-api/attachment/thread-249418047-6997650860681061579.png

https://storage.googleapis.com/support-forums-api/attachment/message-250515018-3732100919889471828.png

Goal
Display "TODAY" view of Google Calendar DAY view (not Agenda) in an embedded link code for iframe.

Observations
Using mode=DAY link code, page displays one day, but not *TODAY* (displays day before's day view).

Requirements
No desire to use AGENDA mode.  mode=AGENDA displays correct date (as expected).